# React - add ellipsis character not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to truncate my `title` and add the ellipsis character (`&hellip;`) to display `...` after 49 characters.

I tried this:

```
return title.length > 50 ? `${title.substring(0, 49)}` + "&hellip;" : title;
```

But it isn't working. 
Is there any way to get it to work?

Comment: What is the output it is showing? or if error what is the error it is showing?

Comment: Why not use the actual character (`…`)?

Comment: if you update to `return title.length > 50 ? ${title.substring(0, 49)} + "..." : title;` it should work

Comment: My title has a max length of 50 characters. I figured that if i use `&hellip;` i would allow for 49 more whereas if i use `...` i would only allow for 47 more.

Comment: @GangadharGandi is just prints it as a string, not as `...`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to be in a JSX context to emit html entities, not just a string. This is a security feature to prevent user provided content from adding things to the page that compromise the security of your content.

So something like:

```
return title.length > 50 ? <>{title.substring(0, 49)}&hellip;</> : title;
```

You may need to swap out `<></>` for `<React.Fragment></React.Fragment>` depending on your transpiler setup. Or a `<div>` or a `<span>` would work as well.

Answer (score 6):

I found the answer: instead of using `"..."`, i had to use `"\u2026"`.
https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2026/index.htm